# ZF2 Ajax call returns all information instead of just the id being sent

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework2

I'm trying to select one contract from the dropdown list, but it looks like the Ajax call is returning information for all contracts instead of just the id being sent. Bare in mind that I'm very new to ZF2.

// view.phtml

```
<script>
function loadContractId(id)
 {
    $.getJSON('<?php echo $this->basePath();?>/ajax/getId/'+id+'', function(data) {


    $("#ctrid").text(data["arr"][0].ctr_id);
    $("#ctrspec").text(data["arr"].ctr_spec);
    $("#ctrnutype").text(data["arr"].ctr_nu_type);
    $("#ctrlocationcity").text(data["arr"].ctr_location_c);
    $("#ctrlocationstate").text(data["arr"].ctr_location_s);

   $.each(data["arr"], function (index, item) {
      console.log(item);
   });

    });
    $("#contact_holder").css('visibility','visible');
 }

</script>


<div id="loc_placement_panel" class="p0pup">
  <form name="loc_placement_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/booking/view/add">
      <input type="hidden" name="ph_id" value="<?php echo $ar["ph_id"]; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="pres_status" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="ph_name" value="<?php echo $ar["ctct_name"]; ?>">

      <!--<input type="hidden" name="addon" value="see below">-->
      <strong>Placements</strong><br/><br/>

      <label><strong>Contract:</strong></label>

      <select name="contactlist" id="contactlist" onchange="loadContractId($('#contactlist').val())">
        <?php
                foreach ($ctrLT as $row=>$ar_contracts)
                {
                    echo "<option value='".$ar_contracts['ctr_id']."'>";
                    echo $ar_contracts['ctr_no'];
                    echo "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>

        <div id="contact_holder" style="visibility: hidden">
            <strong>Ctr id: </strong><span id="ctrid" ></span><br/>
            <strong>Spec: </strong><span id="ctrspec" ></span><br/>
            <strong>Nurse Type: </strong><span id="ctrnutype" ></span><br/>
            <strong>City: </strong><span id="ctrlocationcity" ></span><br/>
            <strong>State: </strong><span id="ctrlocationstate" ></span><br/>
        </div>


      <label><strong>User Name:</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="loc_location" id="loc_location" value="<?php echo $ar["ctct_name"]; ?>"  />


      <label><strong>$ltcontracts:</strong></label>
      <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="100" name="loc_location" id="loc_location" value=""><?php '<pre>'; print_r($ltcontracts); '</pre>';?></textarea>


      <br/><br/>
      <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="loc_placement_submit_btn" name="loc_placement_submit_btn" /> -->
      <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="loc_placement_cancel_btn" />
  </form>
</div>
```

// AjaxController.php

```
 // LT contracts
    public function getId($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        return $this->getResortObject('retainedResort',$id);
    }

  // LT contracts
    public function getIdAction() {

        $result = new \stdClass();

        $arr = $this->getContractsTable()->selectLtContracts($id);
        $result->code = Response::STATUS_CODE_200;

        $result->arr = $arr;
        $json = Json::encode($result);
        $response = $this->getResponse(); //new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode($result->code);
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
        $response->setContent($json);
        return $response;
    }
```

// ContractTable.php

I tried also with selected id, (   `$select->where('ctr_id = ?', $id);` ) but it didn't work.

```
public function selectLtContracts($id = 0, array $ar = null) {


    $this->table='allcontracts';
    $select = new Select($this->table);
    $select->where->like('ctr_no', '%LT');
    $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);

    $ar = array();
    if($resultSet)
    {
    $i=0;
      foreach ($resultSet as $row) {

        $ar[$i]['ctr_id']=$row->ctr_id;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_no']=$row->ctr_no;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_spec']=$row->ctr_spec;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_nu_type']=$row->ctr_nu_type;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_location_c']=$row->ctr_location_c;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_location_s']=$row->ctr_location_s;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_nurse']=$row->ctr_nurse;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_type']=$row->ctr_type;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_marketer']=$row->ctr_marketer;
                $ar[$i]['ctr_recruiter']=$row->ctr_recruiter;
        $i+=1;
      }
    }

    return $ar;
  }
```

This is what I'm getting from my console when I select a single contract from the dropdown list:

[image]
Any idea?

Comment: `selectLtContracts($id);` - you take in an $id variable here...but $id is not defined anywhere in the `getIdAction()` method. I don't know your specific framework but it seems fairly obvious you need to define the variable before you can use it. Should be `getIdAction($id)`, perhaps? Check the docs of your framework for how you access input variables sent by the client.

Comment: It's also obvious that you don't use `$id` anywhere in the `selectLtContracts` methods - so even if you were passing an actual value into this method, you're not using it to restrict the results from the database. Hence why it returns a big list instead of a single item.

Comment: That is correct. Thanks. The answer is probably in the model ContractTable.php. I'll figure it out tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I forgot to include in `getIdAction()` the single `'id'` parameter from route:

```
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
```

and in the ContractsTable.php I needed to add [equalTo() predicate](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Predicate.Predicate.html#equalTo):

...

```
if($id!='' && $id > 0)
  $where->equalTo('ctr_id', $id);

  $select->where($where);
```

...